# adhesive for gluing rubber to wood

Tags: glue, stairs

I am replacing rubber tread covers on an old wooden staircase. As far as I can tell, the old ones were simply glued on. They lasted about ten years before they started slipping and cracking where they were pushed over the edge of the actual tread by peoples' feet. I have two questions:

1- What kind of glue should I use for this project?
2- Do I need to strip off the old glue to get a good bond?

Quick answers would be greatly appreciated since I have a narrow window in which to finish this project. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you want to use [contact cement](http://www.homedepot.ca/catalog/caulk-adhesives-sealants/173212).  Make sure both surfaces are clean, apply contact cement, let it set up, and then put the rubber onto the wood.

Comment: So you're saying I would have to strip the wood, correct?

Comment: Strip it or sand it down for the best results.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still haven't started yet, delivery delay.